# mouseenter on dropdown menu select option to highlight an img

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseenter

I have a select option drop down list with some advanced features (it saves all the checked values and displays them as a linear list at the top). I also have a div of several images. I'm trying to create an effect in which when i mouseover an option in the list, the corresponding image will be highlighted (by adding red border).

here is the list in html:

```
   <select  id="a20" multiple="true" tabindex="1" style="text-align:center;">
       <option  value="round">round</option>
   <option value="rectangle">rectangle</option>
   <option value="pear">pear</option>
   </select>
```

and then the images:

```
 <div class="img" style="position:relative; top:-160px; left:350px; width:1200px;">
     <img id="round" class="item" src="images/round.jpg">
     <img id="rectangle" class="item" src="images/joe2.jpg">
     <img id="pear" class="item" src="images/pear.jpg"> 
 </div>
```

here is my CSS:

```
.item{position:relative; float:left;width:80px; height:100px; margin:1px 1px; float:left; align:bottom}

.hover{border:4px solid red;}
```

my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var C = $("#a20 option");
C.on('mouseenter', function(){
var V = $(this).val();
$("#V").addClass("hover");})

 C.on('mouseleave', function(){
 var V = $(this).val();
 $("#V").removeClass("hover");})


})
```

the javascipt was inspired by this example, which works: http://jsfiddle.net/WJaVz/21/

why doesn't it work in my case? =(

Comment: What are we supposed to see in that example?

Comment: what do you mean, the link? we're supposed to see exactly what it does.it works. it's what I'M trying to do that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting like this:
    $("#V")
Select like this:
    $("#" + V)
jQuery cant pick out variables within quotations.

Comment: please help, anyone??

Answer (score 0):

haha, i found out i was totally right. all i had to do is change the code to C.mouseenter(function()....
i kept all the libraries as they were, and it's working. i still have the problem of the dropdown function though. when i include the function in the code the hover stops working.